# How can I replace all even matches of a word in a string?

Tags: php

I am trying to convert Remarkup to MediaWiki markup.

In Remarkup, code blocks use the following syntax:

````
```
some code
```
````

I would like to replace that with MediaWiki's code block syntax, which is as follows:

```
<code>
some code
</code>
```

As you can see, I can't just use preg_replace() for this, since odd occurrences (of ```` ``` ````) should be replaced with `<code>` and even occurrences with `</code>`.

How can I do this in PHP?

Comment: So show us what you have written so far to try to do this

Comment: Do the occurrence of 4 first, then the occurrence of 3 using `preg_replace()`?

Comment: I don't know how similar Remarkup is to Markdown, but using a Markdown parser would work a lot better than doing it manually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define custom replacement logic as a callback for `preg_replace_callback`, something like:

````
$count = 0;
$s1 = preg_replace_callback(
    '/```/', 
    function($m) use (&$count) { ++$count; return $count % 2 ? '<code>' : '</code>'; },   
    $s
);
````

Comment: This is great, I did not even know preg_replace_callback() existed. Thank you for your helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a markdown parser to do that.

[ParseDown](https://parsedown.org/) is only one of the multiple choices out there:

````
$parsedown = new Parsedown();

echo $parsedown->text('
```
some code
```
');
````

The result would be: `<pre><code>some code</code></pre>`